# PayPal SDK to allow person to person payment in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal

I'm trying to find a way to integrate PayPal that would allow my users to pay via PayPal to another user right from my platform. I can't seem to find API/SDK for that. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `purchase_units` object, you can set a custom `payee` to be the receiver's email address

See the guide here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/custom-payee/

Comment: Thanks, but this looks like it will be paid from my account? Or can it be done from my user's account?

Comment: Not from your account. (That would be Payouts)